# Как изменить ширину столбцов на Листе2 excel openpylx?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Меняю ширину столбцов с помощью данной конструкции

```
       #Записываем результат в файл   
       result = df3.loc[df1.ne(df3).any(axis=1)]
             with ExcelWriter(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', mode="a") as writer:
                 result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Лист2", header=None, index=False)
             
             #Меняем ширину столбцов
             wb1 = load_workbook(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', read_only=False)
             sheet1 = wb1.active
             sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
             sheet1.column_dimensions['C'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['D'].width = 130
             for r1 in dataframe_to_rows(result, header=False, index=False):
                 ws_mysheet1.append(r1)
             wb1.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')
```

и всё работает на Лист1 но если с помощью её попробовать задать ширину на Лист2 ничего не происходит только повторно добавляется данные в Лист2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

```
 #Записываем результат в файл   
   result = df3.loc[df1.ne(df3).any(axis=1)]
         with ExcelWriter(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', mode="a") as writer:
             result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Лист2", header=None, index=False)
         
         #Меняем ширину столбцов
         wb1 = load_workbook(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', read_only=False)
         sheet1 = wb1['Лист2']
         sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 18
         sheet1.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
         sheet1.column_dimensions['C'].width = 18
         sheet1.column_dimensions['D'].width = 130
       
         wb1.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')
```